# Autosave in Jupyter Notebook distracts me with a pop up page of code. How can I stop this?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, autosave

For some reason every 5 minutes a pop up window appears in my Jupyter Notebook with code.  I believe this is tied to the autosave operation but how can I suppress this annoying pop-up window?

See the picture below;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewi0f.png)

I do not know how to deal with this.